# IzPack: How to use two or more ProcessPanel

Tags: panel, izpack

the first one to check install environment, the second one to process some script.

When I see the official manual, it teach us how to use one ProcessPanel, but do not say how to use two or more.

Setup two ProcessPanel , they process the same content.

Answer (score 0):

So currently there is no way to have two ProcessPanels that don't run from the same ProcessPanelSpec [Izpack Mailing list asking about Multiple ProcessPanels](http://izpack.org/mailing-lists/berlios-lists-archives/izpack-users/2006-October/001042.html)

But if you just need to limit to os, you can use the `<os>` tag inside your `<job>` to restrict it to a certain environment.